# opening a Ui_Form from a mainwindow in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4, qwidget, qmainwindow

Well, this is a problem that has been bugging me for few days. I'm trying to open a Ui_form from a MainWindow. For some reason the child window opens and closes instantly.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # Some Gui Code
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(406, 234)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 406, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton , QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()") , self.NewLog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "New Log", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))



    def NewLog(self):
        app = QtGui.QWidget()
        myapp = new_application_log.Ui_Form()
        myapp.setupUi(app)
        myapp.show()
        #app.exec_()

class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        # Some Gui Code.
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(312, 269)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(Form)
        self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow() # <-- Instantiate QMainWindow object.
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: It looks like it is just a scope issue. Could you post some usable code? You could try creating the variable you set your new UI form to somewhere in the main window class's, that way it won't go out of scope when the NewLog function exits as a quick fix

Comment: That isn't entirely necessary though and that is why I would like to see how you're actually using that code. Right now it doesn't actually do anything with the new form

Comment: @user3591723 : I've added some  code that may help you, but it is not the whole code. Hope it helps.

Comment: As I thought, one way to fix it would be to put a reference to it outside of the function, check answer

Comment: Sorry you got that message before I finished typing it up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to change your newLog to this

```
def NewLog(self):
    app = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.form = Ui_Form()
    self.form.setupUi(app)
    self.form.show()
```

with the `self.form` defined in the `Ui_mainwindow` class

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)

        self.form = None
```

In your code, you are defining the `myapp = Ui_form()` variable inside of the `newLog` function and then it is going out of scope and being deleted right when the function exits. If you were to somehow include some blocking of the function ending you wouldn't technically need to put `self.form` in the `__init__()` of `Ui_mainWindow`. Say, for instance, you had a form that would return require a button hit to close, then you could just do it as you had it, but since you're just `show()`ing a widget, you need to have it survive outside of the function.

---

Edit: For instance, this code would run just fine for the above stated reason--you have to click the button before the function exits

```
def NewLog(self, text='I am open!', buttons=QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok):
   errorBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
   errorBox.setText(text)
   errorBox.setStandardButtons(buttons)
   return errorBox.exec_()
```